# Error on adding Windows Phone 8.0 wp8 platform in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I downloaded Windows Phone 8.0 wp8 platform for Cordova from Github, but while trying to install it in Cordova, I get the following message :
"Error: Your cordova wp-8 platform does not have Api.js"

How can I fix that error? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using node.js, and if so is it the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that the [Windows Phone 8 platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/wp8/index.html) has long been **deprecated** and superseded by the [Windows platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/win8/index.html), also known as *Universal Windows Platform* (UWP). **This platform can deploy apps to both Windows Phone 8.1 as well as Windows 10 devices**, so you should use is instead. Most new plugins also require the new Windows platform to work.

To develop Windows Universal (or Android and iOS) apps with Cordova I advice you to get [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/cordova/) with the Tools for Apache Cordova to get started easily, it includes the UWP SDK and Windows Phone emulators. You only have to first install Node 4.x (x86) and Java SE 8 (x86).